# Outlook.MailItem custom properties issue

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

i have the following situation for my Add-In (Office >= 2010):

I want to add some custom properties to an Outlook.MailItem (property must be mail associated) while the mailtext is written. 
If this mail is sent i want to grap the send event and get the previously set properties again, doing something and removing the properties and continue sending.

Problem if i use PropertyAccessor:
I use it as follows to save the property while writing the mail:

```
string propTag = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/test_property"
mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(propTag, value);
```

And to read the property again on sending the mail:

```
string propTag = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/test_property"
string readProperty = mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(propTag);
```

- works if cached mode is enabled on exchange
- works NOT if cached mode isn't enabled... i can't find the previously setted properties anymore (Exception with unknown property is thrown)

OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) can find the property on sending so does anyone knows how to read the properties in a different way?

I would thank you very much for every help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.save) if you want your changes to be persisted.

Comment: Hey, yes this works... but then it will create an "draft"-Item which i didn't want. OutlookSpy can get it anyway (without "save" call)

Comment: Try to call Save from the Application.ItemSend event handler - the message will be saved anyway.